# Evaluate $\int \sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I have a question to calculate the indefinite integral:
$$\int \sqrt{1-x^2} dx $$
using trigonometric substitution.

Using the substitution $ u=\sin x $   and $du =\cos x\,dx $, the integral becomes:
$$\int \sqrt{\cos^2 u} \, \cos u \,du = \int \|{\cos u}\| \cos u\, du $$

Q: (part a) At what point (if at all) is it safe to say that this is the equivalent of ?
$$\int \cos^2 u\, du = \int \frac {1 + \cos 2u} {2} du$$ (this is easy to solve, btw).

In lectures, it was made abundantly clear that over certain intervals (eg $ 0 \le u \le \pi/2$) that $cos u$ is +ve and is safe to do so, but in the indefinite form, the same argument cannot be made (eg $ \pi/2 \le u \le n\pi$).

Q: (part b) Is it safe to declare it ok due to the nature of the original integral, which, using a sqrt() must return a +ve number? It could then be argued that it was the substitution which artificially added a -ve aspect...

Any suggestions on how to proceed?

PS: This is a 1st year calculus course and am revising for exams ;)

Comment: The original integrand allows for $x$ to be in the interval $[-1,1]$ which means that $\cos$ can be negative. In my experience ignoring this is almost never a problem. Rather than worrying about the details of when $\cos$ is positive or negative, recall that you can always prove that your final answer is correct by showing that its derivative equals the original integrand.

Comment: The lecturer has been pounding into us the need to think correctly on fundamental concerns, which is why I raise it here. Although I understand I can show _equivalency_ by derivation, it is not a proof (as far as I am aware)

Comment: The **definition** of an indefinite integral is that it is the anti-derivative of the integrand (up to an additive constant). There is no more legitimate proof.

Comment: You have it backwards. To do this with trig substitution, $x=\sin u$, not $u=\sin x$.

Comment: @Spencer I don't think that's right. $x$ is in $[-1,1]$, and since $x=\sin(u)$, well, see my answer below.

Comment: @alex.jordan, yes I noticed that as soon as you made your first comment. For some reason I was thinking the substitution being made was $x=\cos(u)$ rather than $\sin(u)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $x$ ranges from $-1$ to $1$, and you are using the substitution $x=\sin(u)$, you can make this substitution with $u\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, and then $\cos(u)$ is unambiguously positive.

Comment: It was the logic of discussion which had me confused. This clarifies the _why_. Recognising the limiting domain (to real numbers) from -1 to 1 is the key ingredient.

Answer (score 2):

You have received good answer which all conclude that $\sqrt{\cos^2 x} = \cos x$.

But, for the time being, let us assume you still ignore if it is safe or not. So, let us write $$\int \sqrt{1-x^2} dx=\pm \int \cos^2 u\, du =\pm \int \frac {1 + \cos 2u} {2} du=\pm \Big(\frac{u}{2}+\frac{1}{4} \sin (2 u)\Big)$$ But now, let us consider the definite integral $$\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-x^2} dx=\pm \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos^2 u\, du =\pm \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac {1 + \cos 2u} {2} du=\pm \frac{\pi}{4}$$ But now, consider now the area between the curve $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ and the $x$ axis. All the curve is above the axis and the area is then positive. So, $\pm$ should be just replaced by $+$.

Is this making things clearer ?

Answer (score 2):

Note that there is a difference between substitution as one initially learns it (let $u=g(x)$ and what in the OP is called "trigonometric substitution."  The latter process, when one is feeling pedantic, is actually called *inverse trigonometric substitution*.

In the example we are discussing, the substitution "really is" let $u=\arcsin x$.  So $u$ naturally lives in the interval $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, and therefore $\cos u$ is non-negative.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: first integrate by parts to get,

$$\int\sqrt{1-x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x=x\sqrt{1-x^2}+\int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,\mathrm{d}x.$$

Now attempt the trigonometric substitution.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: yes, it is safe and doesn't really matter. When you do trig. substitution in your first year calculus course, you are always assuming that $\cos$ is positive as a result you can do:

$$\sqrt{\cos^2 x} = \cos x$$

and not have any problems. Also, take into account what @spencer said; whatever your final answer, you can just find it's derivative and prove yourself right or wrong.

Good luck on your exams!

Comment: We have spent a lot of time on your statement. It is not true at 3*pi/2. I can personally guarantee, that in my course, making that assumption without qualification means loss of marks.

Comment: Absolutely right but for first year, as far as I know, the integral is calculated with keeping in mind that $\cos$ is in between that intervals which you specified, otherwise $\sqrt{\cos^2 x} \rightarrow \cos x$ doesn't make sense. Depending on which textbook you use, go to the trig. substitution chapter and from an example with $\cos x$ it will say specifically that $\cos x$ is bounded between $0 \le x \le \pi/2$

Comment: PS; This is an indefinite integral. No boundaries are specified

Comment: The bounds for the integral and the bounds for the function are not the same. I believe that is where you are confused. All we are saying is that we want to consider $\cos x$ when it is positive and therefore, bound it between those bounds. This doesn't imply that the entire integral is bounded between those.